# How to count a dataset in Orbeon Forms?

Tags: orbeon

I have a HTTP Service that returns an JSON response that Orbeon converts to XML like this:

```
<json type="object">
    <data type="object">
        <timeSlots type="array">
            <_ type="object">
                <label>9:00AM to 9:30AM</label>
                <value>1</value>
            </_>
            <_ type="object">
                <label>10:00AM to 10:30AM</label>
                <value>2</value>
            </_>
        </timeSlots>
    </data>
    <is_success type="boolean">true</is_success>
</json>
```

I've set up an Orbeon "action" that uses Save to Dataset named "time-slots":

[Screen shot showing Save to Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNs8D.png)

But, I can't figure out how to count the dataset in a control.  I've tried adding the following to a control's calculated value:

```
count(fr:dataset('time-slots')/json/data/timeSlots/_)
```

and

```
count(fr:dataset('time-slots')/json/data/timeSlots)
```

I can't figure out the syntax. Any hints or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`fr:dataset()` function](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/extension-functions/extension-form-runner#fr-dataset) returns the root element instead of the document node, just like `doc()`, so you'll want to skip the `json` in your XPath. If you want to count the number of time slots, based on the XML you quoted, the following should do the trick:

```
count(fr:dataset('time-slots')/data/timeSlots/_)
```

Comment: Excellent @jlonge, I'm glad that worked, and thank you for the confirmation. ‑Alex